# How to set viewpoint Graphics3D to a different default orientation?

Tags: graphics

I'd like to have a SphericalPlot3D show up with the "z-axis" oriented horizontally by default.  For example, in

```
With[{asz = 1,
  toff = 0.1,
  axes = Graphics3D[{
     Red, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {asz, 0, 0}}] , 0.05],
     Blue, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, asz, 0}}] , 0.05],
     Darker[Green, .8], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, asz}}] , 0.05],
     Text[ "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(1\)]\)",  {asz + toff, 0, 0} ],
     Text[ "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(2\)]\)",  {0, asz + toff, 0} ],
     Text[ "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(3\)]\)",  {0, 0, asz + toff} ]
     }],

  U = ((Cos[Pi #2 Cos[#1]] - Cos[Pi #2])/Sin[#1])^2 & },

 Show[
  SphericalPlot3D[
   U[t, 1]
   , {t, 0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}
   , PlotRange -> Full
   , PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7]]
   , ImageSize -> 400
   ],
  axes]
 ]
```

my arrow labeled "e_3" points "upwards" in the graphics view.

[image: SphericalPlot3D sample]

I can rotate the image with the mouse, but would like it to be in the horizontal, pointing to the right, without using the mouse.

Comment: What about `SetOptions` in combination with `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another option is to do this by changing viewPoint, ViewVertical,ViewAngle. There are lots of view point dynamic selectors, I use one I found on this thread http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Apr/thread.html#00504  by Alexander Elkins. The idea is to use the mouse to change the 3D until you get the position you want, then copy the values and use them in your code, so that the 3D shape will always have that orientation.

For example, in your case, here are the values needed

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And here is the code below. So you can now use these numbers in your original code.

```
Manipulate[
 axes = Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {asz, 0, 0}}], 0.05], Blue, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, asz, 0}}], 0.05], 
    Darker[Green, .8], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, asz}}], 0.05], Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(1\)]\)", {asz + toff, 0, 0}], 
    Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(2\)]\)", {0, asz + toff, 0}], Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(3\)]\)", {0, 0, asz + toff}]},
   Axes -> Dynamic[axes],
   Boxed -> Dynamic[boxed],
   ImageSize -> 300
   ];
 U = ((Cos[Pi #2 Cos[#1]] - Cos[Pi #2])/Sin[#1])^2 &;
 Show[
  SphericalPlot3D[U[t, 1], {t, 0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi},
   PlotRange -> Full,
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7]],
   ImageSize -> 400,
   ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp],
   ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv],
   ViewAngle -> Dynamic[va],
   ViewCenter -> Dynamic[vc],
   SphericalRegion -> Dynamic[sr],
   Method -> {"RotationControl" -> Dynamic[rc]}
   ], axes],
 {{vp, ViewPoint /. Options[Graphics3D], "ViewPoint\[Rule]"}, InputField}, {{vv, {0, 0, 1}, "ViewVertical\[Rule]"}, InputField},
 {{va, Automatic, "ViewAngle\[Rule]"}, InputField}, {{vc, {{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}}, "ViewCenter\[Rule]"}, InputField},
 Row[{Labeled[Checkbox[Dynamic[sr]], "SphericalRegion\[Rule]", Left, Spacings -> 0],
   Labeled[Checkbox[Dynamic[axes]], "Axes\[Rule]", Left, Spacings -> 0], 
   Labeled[Checkbox[Dynamic[boxed]], "Boxed\[Rule]", Left, Spacings -> 0], 
   Labeled[Checkbox[Dynamic[tube]], "Tube\[Rule]", Left, Spacings -> 0]}], {sr, {True, False}, None},
 {axes, {False, True}, None}, {boxed, {False, True}, None}, {tube, {False, True}, None},
 {{rc, "ArcBall", "RotationControl\[Rule]"}, {"ArcBall", "Globe"}}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sp3d = With[{asz = 1, toff = 0.1}, With[{axes =  Graphics3D[{Red, 
       Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {asz, 0, 0}}], 0.05], 
       Blue, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, asz, 0}}], 0.05], 
       Darker[Green, .8], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, asz}}], 0.05],
        Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(1\)]\)", {asz + toff, 0, 0}], 
        Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(2\)]\)", {0, asz + toff, 0}], 
        Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(3\)]\)", {0, 0, asz + toff}]}], 
       U = ((Cos[Pi #2 Cos[#1]] - Cos[Pi #2])/Sin[#1])^2 &}, 
   Show[SphericalPlot3D[U[t, 1], {t, 0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7]], ImageSize -> 400], axes]]];

Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[ Pi/2, {0, 1, 0}]] &, 
  sp3d, {1}], PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]