# How can I project a Torus along the x-axis?

Tags: plotting

Making a Torus seems simple enough, but how do I project it along the x-axis?

For example, I want to rotate this:

[image: flat torus]

And make it look like this:

[image: x-axis torus]

Thanks for who can help!

Comment: related q/a: [How to set viewpoint Graphics3D to a different default orientation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76164/125)

Comment: maybe `ParametricPlot3D[ RotateLeft@{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[u]}, {u, 0,
   2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, ViewPoint -> {-2., -1.5, 2.5}]`?

Comment: `RotateLeft` seems to have done the trick. Did you want to write that up in an answer? I can then edit it with the final code. Thank you

Comment: crockpotveggies, just posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot3D[ RotateLeft@{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[u]}, 
  {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, ViewPoint -> {-2., -1.5, 2.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Direct swap among orthogonal vector components:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), 
  Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), 
  Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u])}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```